# QDockWidget Tab Stylessheet

Tags: qt

How I can change these tabs at the bottom from the design? I just can't find the prefix needed to color the tabs to match my design.

[image]

Comment: Are those two tabs part of a `QTabWidget`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those tabs are part of a `QTabWidget`, you can either modify the stylesheet in Designer with something like this:

```
QTabBar:tab { color: white; border: 2px solid #00FFFF; background-color: gray;}
```

Or you can do it via code like this:

```
ui->tabWidget->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral ("QTabBar:tab { color: white; border: 2px solid #00FFFF;  background-color: gray;}"));
```

[image]

You would obviously need to change the colors in the example to the colors you would want. You should also read [Customizing QTabWidget](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar) for more examples and the full reference of what is possible.